# Does Cycles support all (relatively new) CUDA GPUs?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, performance

Are there any limits on the CUDA GPUs that Blender will support (besides really old ones)?

I thought I heard somewhere that Blender doesn't support workstation class (NVIDIA Quadro) GPUs.  But I have a couple friends with Dell m3800 laptops, and Cycles renders fine on it's Quadro k1100.

Are there any certain specs or features which I should look for to make sure Cycles will support it, or is CUDA enough?

*Note: personally I am really just interested in workstation class GPUs since I want to be able to run other software (AutoCAD, Inventor, SolidWorks, Photoshop, etc.) which demand workstation class.  But for the sake of generality I'd like to leave the question genral.*

Comment: I think so, you will have to check specifics on a device-by-device basis. Check the CUDA version, etc

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ I am asking what specs to look for.  For instance I am considering the brand new [Quadro m4000](https://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-m4000).  What should I look for?

Comment: here it seems that quadro versions should be supported http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Supported_platforms also http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?328171-Anyone-using-Quadro-s-in-Blender. But I don't have one, although I'm interested for next laptop to support Blender 2.8+ :)

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks for the links.  Though the first one looks pretty old, it says Brecht (who is no longer full-time with Blender) is on a Core 2 Duo!  Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPU Rendering Page: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Blender supports GPU rendering of CUDA cards with computing power 2.0 and above. (See chart here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

So as long as the GPU is on the NVIDIA CUDA chart with a processing power of atleast 2.0, you are good to go. If it not on the chart you are running a gamble whether it will work or not. (Unless of course your friend confirms specfic GPU will work because he has tried it.)

As for what to *Specfically* look for, I am not exactly the expert but I can say that Blender cannot render a scene IF the size of the scene is larger than the memory of the video card. For example:
**A scene that is 2.5 gb will not render on a 2gb video card.
A scene that is 2.5 gb will render on a 3gb video card.**

And obviously try to shoot for a higher porcessiung power when buying. Here is a 'blenchmark' sheet for GPUs: http://blenchmark.com/gpu-benchmarks

I personally use the GTX 970.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  (I'm looking at the [m4000](https://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-m4000), which has 8GB of GDDR5 so scene size shouldn't be an issue!)

Comment: @Pythogen for dual (of more) GPUs the **memory is not shared** 2 cards with 2gb are limited to 2gb. Moreover, if there is a card that has less memory the rest of the cards will be limited to the size of the smallest of the cards.

Comment: @cegaton thanks for the correction! Always appreciated:)